# Jquery Mobile List View Issues

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

We have a simple Jquery Mobile app and on some devices, not all, they get random/weird characters displaying between each list element. This text is not part of the html code at all and we are pulling our hair out trying to figure out whats causing this.

Picture of issue below:

[List View Issue](http://mycustomerconnect.com/listview.png)

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: post pics inside the question.

Comment: Please post your code and even create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on jsFiddle. It only is a problem on android 4.4+ with chrome browser. Using Jquery mobile 1.3.2. Click the link above to view picture as I don't have enough rep to attach picture.

Comment: Please post your HTML markup for the page anyway.